# たくさん人 or たくさんの人

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage

I know the more grammatically correct version would be the Takusan NO hito, yet I'm sure I've read and heard both in Japanese media. Is the first a more colloquial way of saying it, or are there differences?

Comment: To be clear, たくさんの人 is **not** more grammatical. Both are grammatical and can be used in formal sentences.

Comment: Yes but I don't really see how the above links answer my question... Maybe you can explain a bit?

Comment: たくさん in たくさん人がいます modifies the verb います because it works as an adverb. たくさんの in たくさんの人がいます modifies the noun 人 because it works like an adjective. Adverbs have more freedom in terms of word order, and 人がたくさんいます and たくさん人がいます are interchangeable. In general, Japanese people prefer adverbial expressions when it comes to counting or measuring something, and that's why you hear たくさん人がいます more often.

Comment: Okay I understand now, thanks